# What nation in Eberron uses a crown as its symbol?

Tags: dnd-5e, eberron, content-identification, art

[The art on pages 12 and 13 of *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/welcome-to-eberron#TheLastWar) shows two opposing armies.

The army on page 12 is mostly undead with what might be a living officer at the front, which makes me think of Karrnath - while the army facing them on page 13 appears to be primarily warforged.

If I read right, house Cannith - the family that created warforged - sold them to opposing sides of the Last War. The only indicator who the warforged on page 13 fought for was a flag or standard showing a jeweled crown. Does anyone know what nation had a crown on its flag (if any)?

Comment: I don't own that book, does it look like the one on this page: https://eberron.fandom.com/wiki/The_Aurum

Comment: @AllanMills- the symbol in the book didn't have a chain surrounding the crown.

Answer (score 7):

The D&D 3.5e Eberron supplement *Five Nations* describes the heraldry of every nation. Cyre is the one we’re looking for:

> #### Cyre at a Glance
>
> Data based on the Cyran census of 992 YK and accurate as of the Day of Mourning.
> […]
> **Heraldry:** Crown and bell on a field of green, above a hammer and bellows

<sup>(*Five Nations* pg. 78)</sup>

Of note, the art used in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* on pages 12–13 is actually recycled from *Forge of War*, a 3.5e Eberron adventure. The warforged with the crown shield was actually used as the cover of this work. *Forge of War* was set during the Last War, and so this art almost certainly depicts a battle during the Last War, and so we can be sure that the two sides are each one of the Five Nations (and not some other army). That being the case, only Cyre fits the bill for the crown.

For fun, the others are

- **Aundair:** “The head and wings of a dragonhawk, on a field of blue, beneath the tome of knowledge and grains of unending wheat”
- **Breland:** “A roaring bear surrounded by gold wyverns on a crimson shield”
- **Karrnath:** “A blood-red wolf head on a shield of silver and black”
- **Thrane:** “A silver sword set beneath the symbol of the Silver Flame”

Each of these is depicted except for Cyre, which is blank, and Thrane, which shows the holy symbol of the Silver Flame (silver arrowhead with an etching of flame on it), but not the silver sword set beneath it.

I can confirm for you that the banner held by a zombie on page 12 of *Rising from the Last War* matches the heraldry depicted for Karrnath next to the above description on page 98 of *Five Nations*.

*Eberron Campaign Setting*, the original description of Eberron (again for D&D 3.5e), also depicts heraldry for each of the dragonmarked houses. Each depicts a magical beast with an object representing the house’s specialty above it:

- **Cannith:** A gorgon with an anvil and smith’s hammer above it, set on a shield over a gear.
- **Deneith:** A chimera on a purple shield, with a spiked gauntlet holding a what appears to be a two-ended dagger.
- **Ghallanda:** A blink dog surrounded by representations of farming and harvest: wheat, grapes, and scythes.
- **Jorasco:** A griffin surrounded by a laurel wreath, a pair of hands (healing hands?), and some acorns.
- **Kundarak:** A manticore on a black shield with gold trim, with a crown above and flames around.
- **Lyrandar:** The tentacles of a kraken emerging from an abyss set within a shield, with lightning bolts and waves around and a pearl at each of the top and bottom.
- **Medani:** A basilisk on a black shield trimmed in gold, surrounded by eyeballs on fleshy-looking stalks, with a sword on either side and a few coins scattered in front of the basilisk.
- **Orien:** A unicorn on a purple shield, with a golden crescent moon as well as strange pointy symbols in gold and purple on either side.
- **Phiarlan:** A hydra on a black shield that is set askew, with black-and-red ribbon around it that kind of mimics the hydra’s necks.
- **Sivis:** A cockatrice on a red shield with silver trim, with a scroll in one corner and a quill in the other, with a lit candle above and rubies on either side.
- **Tharashk:** A dragonne on a red shield with gold trim, with thorns around the upper corners and a yellow star above.
- **Thuranni:** A displacer beast on a black shield with silver trim. Clawmarks stretch from the point of the shield to the displacer beast’s claws, and the shield itself has an odd, “thorny” design.
- **Vadalis:** A hippogriff on a black shield with silver trim, and leaves around and a tree on top.

So House Kundarak also has a crown as part of its emblem, but House Kundarak shouldn’t have been in a battle against Karrnath (Dragonmarked Houses are neutral in the affairs of the kingdoms by treaty).

Comment: "House Kundarak shouldn’t have been in a battle against Karrnath" It's plausible that Karrnath could have been the aggressor, there, by attacking a Kundarak bank vault or something. They might be neutral in the wars between the nations, but they are allowed to defend themselves and their assets.

Comment: @nick012000 Sure, but considering the topic of _Forge of War_ and this art’s original placement on the cover and first pages of that book, that isn’t what the art’s depicting.